# Creating a namespace dictionary from pyxb binding?

Tags: namespaces, pyxb

Is there a way to create a dictionary of namespaces from a pyxb binding class?

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary mapping what to what?

The set of all namespaces known to PyXB (which is defined by the set of binding modules that have been imported) can be obtained from `pyxb.namespace.Namespace.AvailableNamespaces()`.  The elements are [Namespace](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/api/pyxb.namespace.Namespace-class.html) instances.